# SPFx: Problem with loading schema in manifest JSON

Tags: sharepoint, jsonschema, web-parts, spfx, manifest.json

I'm having problem with loading $schema in SPFx within my new web part for SP. Web part is working on benchmark.aspx but my whole manifest is not being processed so I can't set preconfiguredEntries and it's big problem for me.

error is:
Problems loading reference 'https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-manifest-base.schema.json': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.(768)

Any idea on this issue please?

```js
{
  
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-web-part-manifest.schema.json", 
    
  "id": "56dab116-67ba-453f-883d-b7a11690e965",
  "alias": "ReadListWebPart",
  "supportedHosts": ["SharePointWebPart"],
  "componentType": "Webpart", 
  
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifestVersion": "2",

  
  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  

  "preconfiguredEntries": [{
    "groupId": "5c03119e-3074-46fd-976b-c60198311f70", 
    "group": { "default": "Other" },
    "title": { "default": "read-list" },
    "description": { "default": "popis web party" },
    "officeFabricIconFontName": "Page",
    "properties": {
      "vedouci_velke_foto": true,
      "asistenti_pod_vedoucim": false, 
      "nazev_web_party": "To jsme my"   
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the manifest.json, will be the same as yours, have the following waring:

[image]

Then tested to access "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-web-part-manifest.schema.json" in my local, no problem, still can be accessed.

After this, I tested to output the preconfigured properties in React SPFX Web Part like this:

[image]

Props.ts

[image]

WebPart.ts

[image]

.tsx

[image]

Still able to output properties:

[image]

In conclusion, you can just igore this issue, it's still able to read preconfiguredEntries.

Comment: thank you a lot, it probably really doesn't have any effect
it also helped me realized that manifest.json is being translated during "gulp serve" and that I can't test its content just by F5 workbench

Comment: Hi Vochomurka, yes, using gulp serve, it could be running as expected. And if my reply is helpful to you, you could choose to Accept as answer so that it could help others who have similiar question in the forum. Thanks very much :)